# Как предотвратить дублирование чекмаркера по нажатию на ячейку в таблице?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mobile-development

Создал таблицу из трех секций, добавил нажатие чекмаркера. Не могу убрать дублирование чекмаркера в таблице на нижеследующих ячейках от нажатых.

```
import UIKit

class AllExersiseTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    //создаем секции
    struct Objects {
        var sectionName: String!
        var sectionObjects: [(name: String, image:String)]!
    }

var objectsArray = [Objects]()

//создаем масив с ячейками для предотвращения дублирования чекмаркеров в таблице по нажатию
var allExersiseTable = [Bool](count: 15, repeatedValue: false)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    objectsArray = [Objects(sectionName: "Standing", sectionObjects: [(name: "Приседания", image:"bb"), (name: "Отжимания", image:"bt"), (name: "Подтягивания", image:"ca"), (name: "Прыжки", image:"co"), (name: "Бег", image:"de")]), Objects(sectionName: "Sitting", sectionObjects: [(name: "БЕГ", image:"ru"), (name: "ПРЫЖКИ", image:"al"), (name: "ПРИСЕДАНИЯ", image:"au"), (name: "ОТЖИМАНИЯ", image:"es"), (name: "ТОЛЧЕК", image:"fr")]), Objects(sectionName: "Special", sectionObjects: [(name: "БЕГ", image:"ru"), (name: "ПРЫЖКИ", image:"al"), (name: "ПРИСЕДАНИЯ", image:"au"), (name: "ОТЖИМАНИЯ", image:"es"), (name: "ТОЛЧЕК", image:"fr")])]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return objectsArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return objectsArray[section].sectionObjects.count
}
//нажатие на ячейку
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    if cell!.accessoryType == .None {
        cell!.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        self.allExersiseTable[indexPath.row] = true
    } else {
        cell!.accessoryType = .None
        self.allExersiseTable[indexPath.row] = false
    }
    //убираем эфект нажатой ячейки
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    //отображаем элементы ячеек
    cell.textLabel?.text = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row].name
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row].image)
    //для предотвращения дублирования чекмаркеров в таблице по нажатию
    cell.accessoryType = allExersiseTable[indexPath.row] ? .Checkmark : .None
    //цвет чекмаркера
    cell.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{
    return objectsArray[section].sectionName
}

}
```

Comment: а что такое чекмаркер?

Comment: у меня ваш код нормально сработал. где то в другом месте видимо проблема

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно хранить все ячейки в массиве. Создай отдельный класс для ячейки и внутри этого класса отлавливай нажатия. Затем в ячейке объяви протокол методы которого ты и будешь вызывать у делегата своей ячейки. При создании ячеек объявляй им делегатом таблицу. Затем при нажатии в ячейке ты можешь её саму передать в метод делегата. потом вызвав у таблицы indexPathForCell: ты узнаешь индекс нажатой ячейки ну а дальше простой сортировкой уже выберешь какие из ячеек тебе нужно обновить, а какие нет.
Возможно не самое лаконичное решение, но это точно поможет.
Надеюсь объяснил доступно